# SQL - Order By Sum of Multiple Tables Sharing Common Field

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, union

I have 2 different tables sharing the same column names.  The tables list the same products which are identified by 'id'.  The products have different revenues throughout both tables and are listed multiple times in each table.

I would like to sum the revenue of the same products across the 2 tables and ORDER BY the sum.  Result is sorting the highest revenue products first.

I've tried JOIN and UNION but can't seem to figure out the right solution.

UNION query I tried...

```
SELECT id, SUM(rev) as total 
FROM (
        SELECT id, rev FROM table1 UNION ALL
        SELECT id, rev FROM table2 UNION ALL
) 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

JOIN query I tried...

```
SELECT table1.id, 
       table1.rev, 
       table2.id,
       table2.rev, 
      (table1.rev + table2.rev) as revenue
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

Comment: is the ID and REV the same paring for both tables?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: The IDs are the same in both tables and listed multiple times in each.  The rev is different on row.

Comment: mysql, sorry i removed the other

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You needed:

1. one UNION ALL, not two.
2. a GROUP BY, that gives the break field.
3. An alias for the subquery (I used AllRevenue - you can use any valid name.)

```
    SELECT id, SUM(rev) as total  
    FROM (
            SELECT id, rev FROM table1 UNION ALL
            SELECT id, rev FROM table2 
    ) AS AllRevenue  
    GROUP BY id  
    ORDER BY total DESC
```

The join approach would have worked if you used a FULL OUTER JOIN, because some ids may be present in one table but not the other, but that is usually less performant.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to group on the ID then... unless I'm missing something.

```
select d.* from (
SELECT 
    table1.id, 
    Sum(table1.rev) + Sum(table2.rev) as revenue
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY
    table1.id) d
order by d.revenue
```

Comment: Inner Join only works if both tables have all the IDs. If any are missing from either table, you need a FULL outer join.

Comment: Yes, that's true at @PaulChernoch, but OP satated *I would like to sum the revenue of the **same products** across the 2 tables*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, SUM(rev) as total 
FROM (
        SELECT id, rev FROM table1 UNION ALL
        SELECT id, rev FROM table2 
) 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.